# Video Recording in Android with both cameras

Tags: android, frameworks, android-camera, video-capture, android-camera-intent

I would like to create an application that would record video with a simple switch button to change the camera source between front and back camera...

Is it possible with the current android framework or some modification has to be done in drivers etc., to do this seamlessly? Any idea how much latency it may incur?

Any suggestions would help... Thanks